# How to create easy accordions in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

Is there a way to easily implement accordions in Drupal 8.
Till now, i've done it with field collection (or paragraph) but my client wish to can put an accordion everywhere in a content where he want. with the fields, i need prepare it on the template.

So i think on something like a shortcode known in WordPress:

```
[accordion]
    [accordion-item id="item-1" title="Title of accordion item"]Drop-down content goes here.[/accordion-item]
    [accordion-item id="item-2" title="Second accordion item"]Drop-down content goes here.[/accordion-item]
    [accordion-item id="item-3" title="A Third accordion"]Drop-down content goes here.[/accordion-item]
[/accordion]
```

Or is there maybe some kind of a page builder module for Drupal which allows that and gives a bit more flexibility creating the content?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drupal 8 - creating an accordion field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48153998/drupal-8-creating-an-accordion-field)

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48153998/drupal-8-creating-an-accordion-field/53220233#53220233, which proposes a reasonably easy solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so here's a very custom solution (not as easy as requested), but still, I guess I'd do it this way. You'll need [FieldGroup](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) module and theme preprocesses knowledge.

- Add an extra field in your form(s). It will be a Fieldgroup of a titre input and a body textarea. Configure it so the user can add an infinite amount of elements.
- Now lets say you add this token in your wysiwyg : **[accordion]**.
- In you theme, create a preprocess function for your node (THEMENAME_preprocess_node), and get the wysiwyg content. Search for the token, and if it's there, place the Fieldgroup content there.
- Don't forget to hide the Fieldgroup content on the display.
- Finally, in your theme, add an accordion library (or jquery-ui accordion from the core) and apply it on your injected html.

It should do the work.

**Edit** : You can also go with [Views Accordion](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_accordion). But I think it would be a less interesting solution for your client UX.

Comment: thanks, sure a good hint but i will try to find a more easier way, maybe it exist and when not, then i will go with yours.

Comment: [Views accordion](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_accordion) is the easiest way, but not necessary the best if you want to consider your client's user experience.