# Drupal 8 - creating an accordion field

Tags: list, accordion, drupal-8

In Drupal 8 -- I want to modify the basic-page content type to be able to support an "accordion field type"

I've seen the list field type - that can have unlimited fields -- but I am looking for a solution that can feature -- header/body - type features.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no module to handle this for you, the solution is to create unlimited Entity Reference in your content type, it must have two fields, `Title` and `Body` as you want, and to convert it to accordions you should customize new entity field theme and implement accordion there.

Another solution is, handle it by https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bootstrap which support accordion or https://www.drupal.org/project/faqfield module :

```
Features:
Configurable default text formats
Configurable answer widget
Types: Normal textareas, textfields and formatable textareas
Formatable textareas for any Wysiwyg editor
Configurable number of rows for textarea widget
Field formatters
jQuery Accordion UI
Simple themeable text
Definition list (HTML <dl>)
Anchor link list
Accordion display options
Choose first active question
Collapse open questions
Event to open/collapse questions (eg. mouseover, click)
```

Comment: An "Entity Reference" - I don't see this in the field options?

Comment: Do I create -- a content type - accordion with those 2 field -- and you are saying when I want to reference an accordion node in my page node?

Comment: Its been said - the field group - can do this -- but I can't seem to expose anything like this when I manage the fields in a content type? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/156006/how-to-create-fields-group-as-accordions

Comment: @TheOldCounty FieldGroup is Group Multi Fields as one section, but what you looking for is multi-field according, isn't?

Comment: yes - that's right -- I am sure I saw something like this with drupal 6

Comment: @TheOldCounty I know all of them, I've been working on Drupal since 2007-8, field_collection, double_field, multi_field  etc. I've done something like what you want with views_boostrap view, check this page http://www.chilaak.com/faq , do you want to achieve something like this?

Comment: ^ faq field did what I needed. Also made the accordion on the page too - so that's what I think I used in drupal 6

Answer (score 3):

Drupal core sets you up well for your need--as it does several common UI requirements like accordions. You can reuse existing core assets pretty easily, and if this route meets your requirements, you'll get some admirable maintenance benefits from the fact that core gets more attention from the Drupal community than any given contrib module.

Two ways core could help:

- you can invoke the [jQuery UI Accordion](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/core.libraries.yml#n453) that ships with core.
- you can pattern something on the [Toolbar Menu](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/modules/toolbar/js/toolbar.menu.es6.js#n3), which "Builds a nested accordion widget".

If the first option looks promising, the [Examples module](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) gives an example for how to use the core jQuery assets, specifically focusing on the [accordion](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/examples/-/tree/HEAD/modules/js_example) UI. (That's called serendipity incarnate!) Here's the [javascript code](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/examples/tree/js_example/js/js_example_accordion.js#n6):

```
(function ($) {

  'use strict';

  $(function () {
    $('#accordion').accordion();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

and here's the [module code](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/examples/-/blob/HEAD/modules/js_example/js_example.module#L26):

```
function js_example_theme() {
  return [
    'js_example_accordion' => [
      'template' => 'accordion',
      'variables' => ['title' => NULL],
    ],
  ];
}
```

Couldn't be easier. Note that if a custom module is less suited than [adding the feature in your theme](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/add-javascript-to-your-theme-or-module), you have either option available.