# Drupal 8 Accordion menu

Tags: javascript, drupal, twig, accordion, drupal-8

I just started to create my own **Drupal 8 Theme**, but I have no clue how to configure an accordion (side-)menu like here:

https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_sidebar_accordion

Any tips or tricks would help a lot.

(I'm not very familiar with Drupal 8 or JS)

Comment: Your question is rather vague… Are you asking about expanding menus, theme regions, how to add menus to a region, or the frontend styling of the elements…

Comment: perhaps show us where you get stuck ... your question is too broad

Answer (score 0):

you can create theme region on the custom_theme.info.yml file:

```
regions:
  sidebar_first: 'sidebar first'
```

Show menu on twig template (example: page.html.twig):

```
{% if page.sidebar_first %}
    {{ page.sidebar_first }}
  {% endif %}
```

Add menu to region :

```
admin/structure/block: add block menu to sidebar first region
```

After custom css for menu.

I think you read the documentation [Adding Regions to a Theme](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/adding-regions-to-a-theme)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sir. But I already got that part. Just the expanding menus are missing.

Comment: you can try module : https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_item_extras  or https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_link_attributes

Answer (score 0):

sounds like the part you are missing is how to add the accordion? if so, take a look at [Drupal 8 - creating an accordion field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48153998/drupal-8-creating-an-accordion-field/53220233#53220233)

alternatively, other answers on that thread also mention modules to try.

if you find that you were just missing the piece on applying accordion styling, perhaps mark this question as a duplicate of that one?

Answer (score 0):

[Accordion Menus](https://www.drupal.org/project/accordion_menus) is there in Drupal 8 and you can go for it.